# learning the basics of C programming which can clear my doubts on arrays and strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, substring

I am new to C so this question may seem a bit stupid :P .

I have an array `arr[]` which stores numbers from 100 to 999.

Now, I have to take each element of the array and subtract the subsequent digits.

For example if I have a number in that array as 1234 then I need another array that stores 1,2,3,4 distinctly so that I can perform 1-2= -1, 2-3 =-1, 3-4= -1.

So if I change a data like 1234 to char through typecasting then how to store this char into an array and then break it into 1,2,3,4 so that I can call it in a for loop by `arr[i]`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


int main()
{

  int t,n,w;
  int mod = 1000007;
  scanf("%d",&t);

  while(t--)
  {
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&w);

    int start = 1;
    int end = 10;
    int i,j,z;
    for(i=0;i<=n-2;i++)
    {
      start = start*10;
      end = end*100;
    }
    end--;
    char arr[10000];

    for(i= start;i<=end;i++)
    {
      scanf("%c",&arr[i]);
    }

    int len = strlen(arr);
    int count = 0;
    int Value=0;

   for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    { 
      char b[10000];
      b[0] = arr[i] + '0';
      char arr2[10000];
      int g = strlen(b);

      for(j=0;j<g;j++)
      {
      strncpy(arr2, b + j, j+1);
      }
        int k = strlen(arr2);
        for(z=0;z<k;z++)
        {
           int u = arr2[z] - '0';
           int V = arr2[z+1] - '0';

           if(u>V)
           {
              Value = Value + (u-V);
           }
           else
           {
             Value = Value + (V-u);
           }              
       }
             if (Value == w)
           {
               count++;
           }

     }
         int ans = count % mod;
         printf("%d",ans);


          }
       return 0;
 }
```

Actually its a question from codechef.com called weight of numbers in the easy section of the practice problems

Comment: You need to put here the code that you tried to write- and then you will get help :)

Comment: 1234 > 999 and all your subtractions == -1 so I'm confused

Comment: "1234" would be in array of char already.

Comment: You cannot just convert your integer array to char and extract digits out of it straight. First you need to go through your integer array in a loop, take out one integer each time and try to extract digits out of it, Like while( i >10) int c = i%10; i = i/10; something along these lines

Comment: there are no stupid questions, the only thing stupid about this question is the c++ tag (and maybe the missing code)

Comment: @Swap  "i have an array arr[] which stores numbers from 100 to 999" - 1234 is not a number in the range100-999. So it is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @tobi303: Maybe. But there are lazy people asking questions they could find an answer themselves much easier than asking that question. To me, this qualifies as "stupid questions".

Comment: @tobi303 some people do believe that, but if you are facing a large sign that says "turn left" and you ask "which way should I turn?" ... I was taught that life is about asking the *right* questions.

Comment: @WeatherVane I am not sure if just blindly following the sign without asking questions is always the best thing ;)

Comment: sorry sorry...actually its from 1000 to 9999

Comment: actually i dont know how to use 3D arrays to solve this question..

Comment: https://www.codechef.com/problems/WEIGHT

Comment: here is the question

Comment: so basically i m taking the input n as the number of digits and creating a reference ..like if n= 3 then the number that we start checking from is 100 and end with 999

Comment: You can start by editing your post and indent this messy code. I'm not going to read this question.

Comment: okk.. now it's done :) but without the question it would be very lengthy to explain what my doubt is

Answer (score -1):

you can split number by digits in this way

```
int num = 123;
int digits[3];
for (int i = 2; i >= 0; i--)
{
  digits[i] = num % 10;
  num /= 10;
}
```

Also if you'll cast num to char that wouldn't help you. You'll just get some character if you try to print it. Nothing more will change.